# mailchimp "Segment test" error

Tags: json, mailchimp

im working on mailchimp api. i wanted to create a segment but before creating the segment i wanted to test the condition. so i tried this code

```
{
"apikey": "xxxxxx7e0992xxx1e3bdxxxe03axxx342-us3",
"list_id": "ec3d67c617",
"options": {
    "match": "all",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "field" : "testgrouptitle",
        "op" : "all",
        "value" : "testgroupname"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

after firing this in postman(chrome) im getting this error

```
{
"status": "error",
"code": 506,
"name": "Invalid_Options",
"error": "op=\"all\" is invalid for field=\"testgrouptitle\" and value=\"testgroupname\"" }
```

the error might be the incorrect condition. can anyone tell me what wrong in the json code?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a condition by Group:

- **Field** = "**interests-X**": where X is the Grouping Id from lists/interest-groupings()
- Valid Op(erations): one / none / all
- Valid Values: a comma delimited string of interest groups for the list, just like you'd use in lists/subscribe() - see lists/interest-groupings()

For more information, refer to [the documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/segment-test.php)